# Parse Push Notification Not Working Properly on IOS 8.1

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, push-notification

This is so weird.
I have 6 apps that all of them share the same code, right now using my iPhone 4s it's all work perfectly.
Since I've download all my apps on my iPhone 6 plus 8.1 version, 4 out of 6 of my apps are not working with Push notification (amazingly they all have the exact code in the app delegate).

this is my code for the push notification:

```
- (BOOL)          application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     // xxx = for security reasons 
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"XXXXX" clientKey:@"XXXXX"];

    // more parse setting
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

    if (application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateBackground) {
    // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
    // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced
    // in iOS 7). In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double
    // counting the app-open.
    BOOL preBackgroundPush = ![application respondsToSelector:@selector(backgroundRefreshStatus)];
    BOOL oldPushHandlerOnly = ![self respondsToSelector:@selector(application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)];
    BOOL noPushPayload = ![launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
        [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    }

    //reset my badge of parse.com notification
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    if (currentInstallation.badge != 0) {
        currentInstallation.badge = 0;
        [currentInstallation saveEventually];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)                             application:(UIApplication *)application 
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];                
}

//parse setting
- (void)         application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        // The application was just brought from the background to the foreground,
        // so we consider the app as having been "opened by a push notification."
        [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];

        //reset my badge of parse.com notification
        PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        if (currentInstallation.badge != 0) {
            currentInstallation.badge = 0;
            [currentInstallation saveEventually];
        }
    }
}

// parse anylitics 
- (void)         application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
      fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
         [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what is not working? Are the devices not registering for Push Notifications or simply not receiving the notifications, have you checked the Installations table if they all have a valid deviceToken?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I did forgot to mention, the device not registering for push.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8 registering for remote notifications was slightly changed:

```
    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | .Badge | .Sound
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | .Alert | .Sound
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }
```

On iOS 8 was added new method '`registerUserNotificationSettings`' that tries to register possible notification types both for Local and Remote Notifications.

P.S. Sample provided in Swift, but it easily can be converted to Objective-C.